# Input ID of Google search text field is different when viewed in Firefox DevTools and Firebug

Tags: firebug, firefox-developer-tools

When I check the input `id` value of the Google search text field via the Firefox DevTools, I see the value as `lst-ib`, but when I inspect the same element using Firebug, I see the value as `gs_htif`.

[image: Input ID of Google Search text field is different when viewed through Inspect Element(Q) and Firebug]

So I was wondering why the same field's `id` value is being displayed differently in both tools.

Comment: Note that *Inspect Element (Q)* opens the Firefox Developer Tools, so I adjusted the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

If you carefully look at the HTML structures, in both, Firefox Developer Tools and Firebug, you can see `<input>` tags with `id="lst-ib"` and `id="gs_htifo"`.

Maybe the way we are placing the cursor or the way one of these identifying the element is different from the other.

Comment: In Chrome ID is "q" where as in firefox it showing id "lst-ib" it is dynamic so if you want to find element better to go for another attribute or find an element with different ways like CssSelector, Absolute Xpath,etc..

Answer (score 0):

i think in such cases the best way to get the element is to use xpath .
i faced the same problem when i was starting automation .
you can also use * for mentioning the css locator , but since the css locator is different and does not have anything in common when serched in chorme and firefox , so working with xpath would be a best solution

Comment: Shouldn't you add a small example code snippet to make this answer more helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The Google search website places several `<input>` elements (with the IDs `lst-ib`, `gs_taif0` and `gs_htif0`) over each other (for auto-completion, I guess), which you can see when you carefully look at the HTML structure in the DevTools and Firebug. And you can see their box model highlighted when you hover over them within those tools.

So, in the CSS selector or XPath you wrote in FirePath you should rather search for the id instead of the class.

Comment: When I use id="lst-ib" for selector or Xpath, then only I am able to identify the locator. If I use id="gs_htifo", the locator is not being identified.

Comment: That's because it's a zero at the end of the ID, not an o. I.e. `gs_htif0`.

Comment: By the way, you can [search for XPaths and CSS selectors directly within Firebug's HTML panel](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/HTML_Panel#Search) (since version 2.0). So there is no need to use FirePath for that anymore.